# Intents - Discord - Python - MacOs

Tags: python, macos, discord.py

So here is my code :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ',')

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Discord.py is working fine')

client.run("<Token>")
```

I have found on internet some simple code for discord bot on python, but like a lot of other people I always have the same error ... INTENTS !!!!!

Here is my error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<Users>/Desktop/Discord/BUt.py", line 4, in <module>
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ',')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

PLEASE !! Help me !! I don't know how to do. I'm at the bottom of the hole (this is a french expression to say that you can't take it anymore). For the information I'm french (you have understood) and I'm on mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you made is simple to correct. You defined the same thing twice

`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ',',intents=discord.Intents.all())`

and delete these:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

So your code looks like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ',',intents = discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Discord.py is working fine')

client.run("<Token>")
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found an answer to my problem thanks to Rexy and an other stack overflow's problem on SSL error.

For people who have problem on MacOs like me :

Go on Macintosh HD > Applications > Python*Version* > and double click on `Install Certificates.command`

And now it's suppose to work with the new code of Rexy !!